# How to write a SQL equivalent right join and insert in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to convert a SQL query using Django ORM but not getting how to implement the right join and insert in a single query.

> Below is my SQL query

```
insert into product_inventory
      ([material_stock]
      ,[opening_stock]
      ,[combined_string])
select
       product_inventorytemp.[material_stock]
      ,product_inventorytemp.[opening_stock]
      ,product_inventorytemp.[combined_string] 
from product_inventory right outer join product_inventorytemp 
     on product_inventorytemp.combined_string = product_inventory.combined_string
     where product_inventory.combined_string IS NULL
```

> Product Inventory and Product Inventory Temp Model

```
class ProductInventoryTemp(CreateUpdateModel):
material_stock = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("MaterialStock"), max_length=255)
opening_stock = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("OpeningStock"), max_length=255)
combined_string = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_("Combined String"), editable=False, db_index=True, max_length=255
)
```

> Below is the Django ORM query that I have tried so far

```
ProductInventory.objects.filter(
            combined_string__isnull=True
        ).select_related()
```

Can someone please help me highlight what exactly wrong is with my ORM query, or it would be good to provide an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share ```product_inventorytemp``` and ```ProductInventory``` models ?

Comment: @Ram I have added the model which I'm using for both ProductInventory and ProductInventoryTemp as there is no difference between the columns.